# How to get first row in BigQuery without limit or group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to update a table by using following SQL Statement:

```
UPDATE
  myTable AS w
SET
  w.age_difference=(
    SELECT
      (r.allowed_age - w.age) AS age_difference
    FROM
      myTable2 AS r
    WHERE
      r.name=w.name 
      )
```

The subquery delivers more than one row that's why I'm getting an error. `LIMIT` and `GROUP BY` are also not allowed in a subquery while using UPDATE. It will be for me fine just to determine the first row in the subquery. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: What value do you want when a person has several, different ages?

Comment: It's if I get only one value in my case and it's INT

Comment: it is still not clear - do you have multiple rows for the same name in myTable2? if so, which to be used for difference calculation? please clarify so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
UPDATE myTable w
    SET w.age = (SELECT MIN(w.allowed_age - r.age) AS age_difference
                 FROM myTable2 r
                 WHERE r.name = w.name 
                ) ;
```

EDIT:

You are not looking for a *particular* difference, so preaggregating should work:

```
UPDATE myTable w
    SET w.age = w.allowed_age - r.age ;
FROM (SELECT MIN(r.age) AS age
      FROM myTable2 r
      GROUP BY r.name
     ) r
WHERE r.name = w.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
UPDATE `<your-table>` w
    SET w.age_difference = r.allowed_age - w.age 
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(allowed_age) AS allowed_age, name
                 FROM `<your-second-table>`
                 GROUP BY name
                ) r 
WHERE r.name = w.name;
```